# Apache ODE - how do i get the process id after the instance is created?

Tags: apache, bpel, ode

i have deployed ODE as a web service and my client app is communicating through the ode events. currently to get the instance id, we are capturing the instance create event and querying all the instances to match the correlation. this is not very efficient and as the number of instances increases, this will be a performance hit. what is the best way to get the instance id as soon as the process instance is created by ODE.

second issue with the above approach is that if the next task in the process is also started and the corresponding event is fired by ODE, we do not have a way to associate this task with the process id until we figure out the process id with the first event which may be delayed due to its asynchronous nature?
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The current process instance is stored in an extension variable called `$ode:pid`. You can assign this value to a response variable (e.g. to the instantiating request) and use it to initialize a correlation set.

```
<assign>
  <copy>
    <from>$ode:pid</from>
    <to>$response.part</to>
  </copy>
</assign>
```

should actually do the job.